# Disable custom dates in Android CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm trying to disable some custom dates in a `CalendarView`. The methods `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate` are useful to set a range, but I want to disable some random days in the calendar and I cannot find how.

Comment: custom dates mean?

Comment: You can not disable dates in android native calender, you only can set Max and Min . You need to use some 3rd party calender library .

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I mean some specific dates in the calendarView.

Comment: @ADM can you suggest some libraries, in an answer?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) is a very known one .

Comment: @ADM thanks, seems great

Comment: Yes it is man . Awesome work by some hard coder..